# MYSQL: JSON_OBJECT with binary data

Tags: mysql

When I select JSON_OBJECT from database it will give me the unexpected result.

`select JSON_OBJECT('test', BIN_TO_UUID('GÇ~pw–’Ú¦[¦£´Æ'));`

`{ "test": "base64:type254:Nzc5NjkyZGEtN2U3MC00N2M3LWE2MWMtNWJhNmEzYjQxZWM2"}`

I want the result like this
`{"test": "779692da-7e70-47c7-a61c-5ba6a3b41ec6"}`

I am using MYSQL 5.7.

Also, when I copy from this query, it won't work.
This code will work properly.
`SELECT JSON_OBJECT('test', BIN_TO_UUID(UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())));`

This is my function for UUID_TO_BIN and BIN_TO_UUID

```
CREATE FUNCTION UUID_TO_BIN(_uuid BINARY(36))
RETURNS BINARY(16)
LANGUAGE SQL  DETERMINISTIC  CONTAINS SQL  SQL SECURITY INVOKER
RETURN
UNHEX(CONCAT(
    SUBSTR(_uuid, 15, 4),
    SUBSTR(_uuid, 10, 4),
    SUBSTR(_uuid,  1, 8),
    SUBSTR(_uuid, 20, 4),
    SUBSTR(_uuid, 25) ));

CREATE FUNCTION BIN_TO_UUID(_bin BINARY(16))
RETURNS BINARY(36)
LANGUAGE SQL  DETERMINISTIC  CONTAINS SQL  SQL SECURITY INVOKER
RETURN
LCASE(CONCAT_WS('-',
    HEX(SUBSTR(_bin,  5, 4)),
    HEX(SUBSTR(_bin,  3, 2)),
    HEX(SUBSTR(_bin,  1, 2)),
    HEX(SUBSTR(_bin,  9, 2)),
    HEX(SUBSTR(_bin, 11)) ));
```

Comment: When I [copy your query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a740a30d37b86db7149c794750b5754), it seems like the length of your string is 25 characters rather than 16. What server version/connection character set are you using?

Comment: I am using MYSQL 5.7
Also, when I copy from this query, it won't work.

Comment: I don't see a [BIN_TO_UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html) function in MySQL-5.7 and I get the error 'Error: ER_SP_DOES_NOT_EXIST: FUNCTION test.BIN_TO_UUID does not exist' in 5.7. Is it a plugin/or function you have create/copied/installed?

Comment: I edited the question and add function I am currently using.

Comment: That helps, change BIN_TO_UUID to return a VARCHAR. I'm not sure your function is right. Seems to be returning a different result than MySQL-8.0

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON_OBJECT inspects the return type when deciding how it will encode the data. BINARY data types get encoded as base64 as the question shows.

Changing the return type on BIN_TO_UUID to VARCHAR will make the encoding use a pure text format when encoding this to JSON,

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using JSON_ARRAYAGG on binary data. I have a custom UUID I store as binary sometimes.  It's kind of like the firebase UUID - binary data, but it works like ascii.  Anyways, since it came up in search, this is what worked for me.

```
JSON_OBJECT(key, CAST(column_name as char));
```

So I'm guessing you could do

```
select JSON_OBJECT('test', CAST(BIN_TO_UUID('GÇ~pw–’Ú¦[¦£´Æ')));
```