# How to decrypt encrypted sql column value using AES_DECRYPTION?

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption

i'm using aes_encrypt for encrypt the column values in SQL, but when i use aes_decrypt for decryption those values it returns me data in base64.

using aes_decrypt:

```
JSON_OBJECT('title', AES_DECRYPT(vn_title , "encryption_key" ))
```

Data i get from using this:

```
base64:type15:ZnJhbmtpZS5qYXNrb2xza2lAeWFob28uY29t
```

i'm also using from_base64 in sql and base64_decode in php on this value but it gives me null value.

How can i tackle this situation?

Comment: Considering you are getting back `base64:type15:` correctly, the aes_decrypt worked correctly. So, you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: i'm saving data in blob form in sql not in base64. no need to get back the data in base64 simple need the original value.

Comment: Yep, confirmed with base64decode.org, the base64 value in your question contains a yahoo.com email address. Please delete this question and ask another one aimed at decoding this string in php. AES_DECRYPT will return the data what was encrypted. If you encrypted a base64 value, then that's what your are going to get back.

Comment: There is no point in trying to decode a base64 value in mysql. Retrieve the base64 encoded data from mysql into a programming language that has built-in support for decoding such values.

Comment: i'm not saving base64 value in sql but why i'm getting this ?

Comment: But if you really want to do the base64 decode in mysql, you could have searched SO and found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507385/base64-decode-a-mysql-column-before-performing-a-where. And yes, you are saving base64 encoded value in mysql. Trust me, AES_DECRYPT is not going to perform a base64 encoding on the returned data.

Comment: Now, i'm getting null value when decoding with from_base64 method.

Comment: Again, pls delete this question and ask a new one one about base64 decode problem with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue of encryption and decryption.
The issue was JSON_OBJECT returns data in base64 form. This was confusing.
So simply i follow this link :

[mysql-json-object-with-binary-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341227/mysql-json-object-with-binary-data)